# Capture webBrowser control response

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, desktop-application

I am using the webbrowser control in C# for our desktop application to run a credit card through a gateway.

Simply, I'm loading the page on the load of the form:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://paymentgateway.com/hosted.aspx?" +
                            "Username=dddd" +
                            "&Password=dddd" +
                            "&MerchantKey=5159" +
                            "&BillingAddress1=123 some street" +
                            "&BillingCity=Somewhere" +
                            "&BillingState=SC" +
                            "&BillingZip=39399" +
                            "&CustomerName=me" +
                            "&Amount=392.00" +
                            "&InvNum=123567" +
                            "&AccountNumber=0133333" +
                            "&CustomerId=0199999");


}
```

(all references changed for security reasons)

The page looks something like this:

[image: Portal]

My question is, **how do I grab the response once the Process button has been clicked** and then close out the form?  I need to know if it was approved and the rest of the information from that point.

I don't have control over the button so I'm not sure how to capture the response.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to subscribe to the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event and handle the response there via Document, DocumentText or DocumentStream.

You would then react appropriately depending on what the output is. For example:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  HtmlDocument document =  webBrowser1.Document;
  //now use any of the methods exposed by HtmlDocument to parse the output
}
```

Comment: I am getting all HTML related things in "document" element but I was unable to get the response. ex:- I call a service. In completed event I need to know the response data for that service(we can see that response in fiddler in TextView tab). How can I get that response details.

Answer (score 0):

In your form you can create a public method to get the information that you can have access from where you call the form. You can call this method on a dialogResult == DialogResult.OK, like this:

```
        object your_info;

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        if (form1.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            your_info = form1.getInfo();
        }
```